# Return url for the first item for which the content part matches pattern

Tags: javascript

How can I return the url part of the first page in pages for which the content part matches pattern (in the style of function 1, case insensitive) but return an empty string if no page is found?

e.g.

> url1(pages,"GREAT") returns "www.xyz.ac.uk"
>
> url1(pages,"xyz") returns ""

Here is my code so far:

```
var pg = [ "|www.cam.ac.uk|Cambridge University offers degree programmes and world class research." , "!www.xyz.ac.uk!An great University" , "%www%Yet another University" ];
var pt = "great";

function url1(pages, pattern) {
    var result = "";
    for (x in pages) {
        current = pages[x].split(pattern);
        result = current[1];
    }
    return result;
}

alert(url1(pg, pt));
```

Comment: Make sure to have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var pg = [ "|www.cam.ac.uk|Cambridge University offers degree programmes and world class research." , "!www.xyz.ac.uk!An great University" , "%www%Yet another University" ];

function find(pages, pattern) {
  var i, l, page, arr;
  pattern = pattern.toLowerCase();
  for(i=0, l=pages.length; i<l; i++) {
    page = pages[i];
    arr = page.split(page[0]);
    if(arr.slice(2).join(page[0]).toLowerCase().indexOf(pattern) >=0) {
      return arr[1];
    }
  }
  return '';
}

console.log(find(pg,'great')); // 'www.xyz.ac.uk'
console.log(find(pg,'xyz')); // ''
```

Fiddle here: http://jsbin.com/uGebeQi/2/edit

Comment: Simple, but it could potentially fail. See my answer.

Comment: @plax Thanks for tip, I've modified the answer and fiddle to take in account the case when content contains separator between url and content as well

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using a regular expression. I feel this is slightly better than blindly splitting on the first character since the content could always contain the *first* character as well.

**Note: The accepted answer was corrected.**

```
function url1(pages, pattern) {
    var rx = /^(.)(.+?)\1(.+)/,
        i = 0,
        len = pages.length,
        matches;

    for (; i < len; i++) {
        if ((matches = pages[i].match(rx)) && matches[3].indexOf(pattern) !== -1) 
            return matches[2];
    }

    return '';
}

//www.xyz.ac.uk
url1(['!www.xyz.ac.uk!An great University! The best in the world!'], 'best');
```

You can always lowercase the `pattern` and the content if you want case-insensitive searches.